# Remove item from cart React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, reactjs, shopping-cart, setstate

I have 2 problems regarding the below code. I want to remove specific items from my cart in React. ( backend Rails). I know that the splice approach is one of the most used but in my case, it does not delete the specific clicked one, but it deletes the last item all the time regardless of the one that I click one.
My second problem is that my Total does not get updated even if the items do get deleted in the wrong way but still get deleted. 
This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BasketPic from './images/cart.png';
import StripePayment from './stripePayment';

class MainBasket extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: true,
      showBasket: false,
      items: this.props.items

    }
    this.toggleBasket = this.toggleBasket.bind(this)
    this.removeItemFromBasket = this.removeItemFromBasket.bind(this)
    console.log(this.state.items)
  }


  toggleBasket(){
   this.setState({toggle: !this.state.toggle});
  }

  showCheckout(){
    this.setState({showBasket: !this.state.showBasket})
  }


  addItemToBasket(itemId){
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/books/${itemId}`)
    .then( item => item.json())
    .then( item => {
      this.state.items.push(item);
      this.state.total += item.price;
      this.setState(this.state);
    })
  }

  removeItemFromBasket(itemId){
    var itemToBeDeleted = this.state.items.indexOf(itemId)
    var deleted = this.state.items.splice(itemToBeDeleted, 1)
    this.setState(this.state)  
  }

  render(){
    var count_items = this.props.items.length
    var total = this.props.total
    return(
      <div className="basketInfo">
        <div className="mainBasketDiv">
          <img src={BasketPic} onClick={this.toggleBasket} />
          <strong><p className="itemsCart">{count_items}</p></strong>
          <strong><p className="checkOutConf">CheckOut</p></strong> 
          <div className={"toggleDiv-" + this.state.toggle}>
            <h3>{"Total: " + this.props.total}</h3>
            <span><h4>{"Items: " + count_items }</h4></span>

            <hr/>
              {this.props.items.map( item => 
                <div className="animated fadeInRight" key={"item-" + item.id}>
                  <h2>{item.title}</h2> 
                  <h6 onClick={this.removeItemFromBasket} className="remvProd">{"Remove " + item.title}</h6>
                </div>
              )}       
            <button onClick={function(){this.showCheckout()}.bind(this)}> Check out</button>    
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <div className={"checkOutStripe-" + this.state.showBasket}>
            <div className="totalBar">
              <p className="totalBarTypography"> Total {this.props.items.length} {this.props.items.length < 2 ? "item" : "items"}</p>
              <p className="totalBarTypography"> Total {this.props.total} GBP</p>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              {this.props.items.map(eachItem => 
                <div className="col-sm" key={"eachItem-" + eachItem.id}>
                  <img src={eachItem.image.url} className="checkOutImg"/>
                  <div className="prodDetails">
                    <h3>{"Product: " + eachItem.title }</h3>
                    <h3>{"Price: " + eachItem.price }</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
            <div>
              <StripePayment 
                description={'BooksMania'}
                amount={total}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}

// module.exports = MainBasket;
export default MainBasket;
```

and this is the code where i set my total and my items initial state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BuyButton from './images/buyButton.jpg';
import MainBasket from './mainBasket';
import CheckOutBasket from './checkOutBasket';
import Reviews from './reviews';

class EachBook extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newReview: [],
      items: [],
      total: 0
    }
  }

  seeAllReviews(bookId){
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/books/${bookId}/reviews`)
    .then( reviews => reviews.json())
    .then( reviews => {
      this.setState({
        bookReviews: reviews
      })
    })
  }

  addReview(bookId){ 
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/books/${bookId}/reviews`,{
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify({comment: this.refs.comment.value}),
      headers: new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token' : this.props.parent.props.parent.props.csrf
      }),
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => alert("There is something wrong with this request"))
    .then( response => {
     this.setState({newReview: response})
    })
  }

  addItemToBasket(itemId){
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/books/${itemId}`)
    .then( item => item.json())
    .then( item => {
      this.state.items.push(item);
      this.state.total += item.price;
      this.setState(this.state);
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>

       <MainBasket items={this.state.items}  total={this.state.total} parent={this}/>
        <div className="container"> 
          {this.props.singleBook.map(indBook =>   
            <div className="indBook" key={indBook.id}>
              <h1>{indBook.title}</h1> <br />
              <h2>{"Author: " + indBook.author}</h2> <br />
              <h4>{"Genre: " + indBook.genre}</h4>
              <h4>{"Price: " + indBook.price}£</h4>
              <img src={indBook.image.url} />
              <div className="button"><img src={BuyButton} onClick={function(){this.addItemToBasket(indBook.id)}.bind(this)}/></div>
              <div className="description">{indBook.description}</div>
              <h3>{this.state.newReview.comment}</h3>
              <div> 
                <h4>Leave a new review</h4> 
                  <textarea ref="comment" type="text" placeholder='Tell us your thoughts '></textarea>
                  <button onClick={ function(){this.addReview(indBook.id)}.bind(this) } >Submit</button>       
              </div>
            </div>
          )}   
        </div> 
      </div>   
    )
  }          
}

export default EachBook;
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know a lot about `react` but for your first problem, `splice` expects index as the first argument so your `this.state.items.splice(itemToBeDeleted, 1)` should be `this.state.items.splice(indexOfItemToBeDeleted, 1)`

Comment: Why are you passing your items down to MainBasket, and then storing that array inside of state inside MainBasket?  This violates one of React's core principles, of "lifting" state up to a parent component. If you indeed go ahead and set new state inside MainBasket, then its already out of sync with its current parent components stored representation of items. Perhaps I am missing if this is your intention for some reason.

Comment: thank you all for your prompt answers @Subas

Comment: thank you all for your prompt answers @Subash i thought that React would understand that the id of the specific element would be relevant to understand the index of it as well but apparently does not so it deletes the last element all the time.  I need to figure out a way to find the index then.

Comment: @Daniel Zuzevich i am still a beginner in React (about 4 weeks so far) i am sure i am doing things not very "best practice" but i will correct them. My Main Basket only renders the items . the state of the items is in my Each Book component. but i took that state "lifted " as you said because i needed to refer to the state of the items so i can use my remove function on them. how do you think it would be best to do it ? many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You’re biggest issue is that you’re mutating `items` in state, so state doesn’t cause a re-render. I would consider using `filter` instead of `splice` and just setting `items` from that like so:

```
removeItemFromBasket(itemId) {
  const items = this.stat.items.filter(item => item.id !== itemId)

  this.setState({ items })
}
```

The `addItemToBasket` should also have that issue. You should not mutate `state` as JavaScript passes objects by reference. You should be using `this.state.total` instead of `this.props.total` in the `render` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you so much for this solution it does make sense and is very elegant but it does nothing unfortunately i do not understand the reason.  I use this.props.total so i can render the total in my basket picture and in my stripe component because the actual state gets rendered in Each Book component . Many thanks again for your time :)

Comment: You may want to reorganize your components and have `MainBasket` not be stateful and just pass everything in from your `EachBook` component. The problem is that you're updating `state`, but you're using `props`. You probably want to just pass down some handlers to `MainBasket` and have the wrapping component actual deal with state.